# A method can't access a member variable of the same class (C++)

Tags: c++, class, static, protected

I wrote a short program to illustrate the principles of inheritance for my school project, but I am having a weird problem. Here is my code: (I have omitted all the code that isn't the problem)

```
class Car
{
protected:
    double fuelLevel;
public:
    void fuelUp(double);
};

void fuelUp(double fuel)
{
    Car::fuelLevel += fuel;
}
```

and this is the build log:

```
||=== Build: Debug in wierdError (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
||In function 'void fuelUp(double)':|
|4|error: 'double Car::fuelLevel' is protected|
|11|error: within this context|
|4|error: invalid use of non-static data member 'Car::fuelLevel'|
|11|error: from this location|
||=== Build failed: 4 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

I have no idea about what this error means and I hope there is somebody who can help me.

Comment: +1 for omitting all the code that isn't the problem.

Comment: You need `void Car::fuelUp(double fuel)`...

Comment: Ok, thanks. I swear I read the code about ten times for this kind of mistake.

Comment: This has been suggested but it doesn't work for this situation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46943651/trouble-with-identifying-why-the-ide-is-saying-undeclared-identifier-in-c

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That function should be written as a member of the class `Car`

```
void Car::fuelUp(double fuel)
{
    fuelLevel += fuel;
}
```

The way you wrote it, it does not have access to any of the member variables in `Car` because it is a different function than the one you declared in the class.

Answer (score 1):

The way that you have it written `Car::fuelLevel += fuel` is triyng to access the variable fuelLevel as if it were `static`.   You need to either make that variable `static` or, more likely what you meant to do, is make the method

```
void Car::fuelUp(double fuel)
{
    fuelLevel += fuel;
}
```

If it makes it any more clear why your original code was wrong, you could also change it to:

```
void Car::fuelUp(double fuel)
{
    this->fuelLevel += fuel;
}
```

Notice in the second variant that you are accessing the field via `this->`, which is implicitly happening in the first version.  Your version had it accessing the field via the class `Car::`.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
void fuelUp(double fuel)
{
    Car::fuelLevel += fuel;
}
```

is not a method. It is some function that has the same name as the method declared inside the class. This code could work if Car::fuelLevel  would be public static data member of the class.

When you define a method outside a class definition you should specify the class to which the method belongs.

```
void Car::fuelUp(double fuel)
{
    Car::fuelLevel += fuel;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must refer your function to a certain class when defining it outside the class. So you should write the `Car` before defining the function. It must be on the form `void car::fuelUp(double fuel)`