# Trouble with identifying why the IDE is saying undeclared identifier in C++

Tags: c++, identifier

I have a class at the moment with these lines of code. What I am struggling with is the function write in that my IDE says "Use of undeclared identifier for root"

Why is this?

```
template<typename T>
    class X
    {
    public:
        const void write(std::ostream & output);

    private:
        std::unique_ptr< TreeNode<Ty> > root;


    };


    const void write(std::ostream & output)
    {
        root->write(output);
    }
```

Edit to show more full extent of the code with the Template.

Comment: What is the return type `const void`?  The `void` return type means that the function doesn't return a value.  How does `const` apply to a value that is not returned?  Maybe you want to place the `const` afterwards:  `void write(std::ostream& output) const;`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A method can't access a member variable of the same class (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20981540/a-method-cant-access-a-member-variable-of-the-same-class-c)

Comment: @ThomasMatthews what does the const at the end mean?

What I am trying to achieve is to write a function which uses the ostream reference to call write on the root. With write being marked as a const.

Comment: The `const` at the end of a method means that the method will not write to any of the class members.

Comment: "Use of undeclared identifier for root": is that what it really says? Doesn't make sense. Sure it isn't "Use of undeclared identifier: root"? Be accurate.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews interesting. never knew that!

Answer (score 1):

Try using the scope resolution operator to tell the compiler that your `write` function belongs to `class X`:

```
const void X::write(std::ostream & output)
{
    root->write(output);
}
```

**Edit 1: templates**
With templates, the syntax becomes:

```
template<typename T>
const void
X<T>::write(std::ostream & output)
{
    root->write(output);
}
```

Comment: It tells me when I do that X is not a class, namespace, or enumeration

Comment: @Scanner Is the definition of `write` after the definition of `X` and in the same file? Or after an `#include` of the file containing the definition of `X`?

Comment: @aschepler the definition of write is after the definition of X and in the same file. They are all under a template<typename T>. The write has been declared under public in the class as const void write(std::ostream & output);

Comment: @Scanner The template parameter is very likely relevant to your problem. You can edit your question to show exactly what you mean.